# Override CSS class on table conditionally

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is decorated with the following class:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-borderless nowrap">
```

For certain users, I want to change the background color of the rows as such:

```
<tr class="@(item.Assigneee == UserSession.User.Id  ? "alert alert-primary" : " ")">
```

but I can't get it to overwrite the table class.  I tried adding !important, but it still displays the background color from the table class.

I see the class is added:

```
<tr class="alert alert-primary odd" role="row">
```

but the background color is struck through, and it's still being displayed by:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the problem is `in which class it says what`.

Comment: MAybe you should just jsfiddle, or codepen to sketch up a working example

Comment: do you see in F12 that class has added??  `alert alert-primary` do you have bootstrap script??

Comment: Yes, I see the class is added.  Added the code that's actually displaying

Comment: It might be a problem with the [specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: `.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd)` has a specificity of `0-0-2-2` while `.alert` or `.alert-primary` is just `0-0-1-0`. You may need `!important` or similar.

Comment: you should add background to `td` instead of `tr`

Comment: Please show your rule that isn't working

Comment: try my solution @TrevorGoodchild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize your CSS this way.

For Bootstrap 4

```
.table-striped tbody tr:not(.alert-primary):nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

For Bootstrap 3.7

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:not(.alert-primary):nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Comment: it would be better to override bootstrap styles rather than edit them - otherwise if you need to upgrade, you will have to remember which styles you have edited and edit them all again (assuming this is bootstrap - looks like it is)

Comment: It is bootstrap.  And I'm not editing them, I'm adding these in a separate CSS file.

Comment: I put the code in the file, added an image to my question showing how it's getting processed.

Comment: are you put my CSS to your file?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you posted it

Comment: add `.table-striped tbody tr:not(.alert-primary):nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) !important;
}`

Comment: Same deal.  It still strikes out the background-color on alert-primary

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild can you please tell me order of your bootstrap.css and your custome css. because it's work on my case.

Comment: and no need to give `odd` class. it's css keyword.

Comment: sorry. but which version of bootstrap you are using right now? 4 or 3

Comment: Custom css is last.  And I'm not adding the 'odd' class, that's coming from the class declaration in the table element.  Using Bootstrap 4

Comment: are you want to add an only .alert-primary class?

Comment: Really I'm just trying to change the background color to the same light blue used in the alert-primary class.  I just thought I'd use the Bootstrap class that was already there.

Comment: last try: ) `.alert-primary { background-color: #cce5ff !important;}` add this to your css file.

Comment: and please also check your style is properly loaded or not

Comment: That worked, thank you for sticking with me patelarpan

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
.table-striped tbody tr.alert.alert-primary:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:red !important;
}
```

do note I am guessing since you haven't post a snippet.

Comment: This is sort of working.  It's making the odd rows red, but the row I want to have the alert-primary on is still getting it's background from the class in the table element.